# How to allow user to type ahead for next window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a WPF application where the user will enter a value into a text box on the main window and press Enter. This activates the window's default button, which does some processing on the data entered, and then pops up a second window where the user will type a second value.

I need to allow for the user to "type ahead". Here's an example of what I mean: The user knows for sure that they want to type a "1" into the box on the 1st (main) screen and a "2" into the box on the second window that pops up, so they quickly type: 1(enter)2. However, due to the processing time on the first entry, the 2nd window hasn't been displayed yet, so the 2nd window isn't getting the "2".

After the user presses (enter) on the main window, I need to system to stop accepting input and "queue up" the user's keystrokes, so that they will go into the next available text box (which is on the 2nd window).

I am porting an application from Borland C++ Builder, and in that environment, this just automatically worked that way. Now, in .NET/C#/WPF, it is not working.

Here is my code for a small test application that I wrote:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DefaultButtonTestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="WPFInputBox" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="283"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="WPFOkButton" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsDefault="True" Click="WPFOkButton_Click">Ok</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsSecond = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WPFInputBox.Focus();
    }

    private void WPFOkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Keyboard.ClearFocus();

        if (!IsSecond)
        {
            // SIMULATE STUFF HAPPENING IN THE BACKGROUND. I.E. A DATABASE LOOKUP
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        var SecondWindow = new MainWindow();
        SecondWindow.IsSecond = true;
        SecondWindow.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Here's how I test it:

Run the application. Type: 1(enter)2 (do it quickly)

You will see that both the 1 and the 2 go into the box on the 1st main window, and nothing goes into the box on the 2nd window.

I thought the problem might be that the focus was still on the text box on the 1st screen, so at the beginning of the OK button event handler, I added a call to Keyboard.ClearFocus(). This did indeed prevent the "2" from going into the box on the first window, but it doesn't go into the 2nd form either. It doesn't go anywhere. That "2" keystroke seems to just vanish.

How can I make this work?

And before anyone asks, I can't just make the 2nd window display before the processing happens, because in my real application, the 2nd window only pops up under certain circumstances, depending on the result of a database query.

Comment: You're putting your UI thread to sleep before you create the second Window, which is the cause of the holdup. Is the second Window dependent on the result of whatever happens inside your Thread.Sleep? Also, at the moment you open the second Window regardless of whether or not the Button was clicked from the first window, i.e. you'll spawn Windows with IsSecond = true on *every Button click in every Window*. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, the second window is dependent on the result of a database query. The real application doesn't use thread.sleep. I just used it to simulate a delay for my test app. Regarding your last question, that was unintentional. I should have put in logic to prevent more than 2 windows. It doesn't affect the issue I'm having though.

Comment: I've tried a couple of things out with this and I'm afraid all I'm seeing are problems. The behaviour you're describing is undesirable for most applications - you *want* your UI to lock up during the query, then accept user input without providing any visual feedback. Because these are 'odd' requirements they're not well supported. Could I suggest that a better approach is just to wait for the query to complete, then ensure that the desired option is readily available? For example, populate a ListBox with your results, put the most chosen option first and accept Enter as a select.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not as simple as that. The use case that I described is actually not the real use case. I posted it that way for simplicity's sake. The real case is that the input is coming from scanning a barcode. The barcode scanner data comes into the application as keyboard input, so the issue is exactly the same. The barcodes that the user is scanning actually contain BOTH values, separated by a carriage return that is embedded in the barcode. So, there is no way for the user to wait before entering the second value. And no, I can't change the barcoding system.

Comment: Why don't you just grab the entire barcode, split the string at the newline, then run consecutive queries with the two strings?

Comment: I don't know how I'd do that. The barcode scanner output comes into the computer as keyboard input. When the 1st value (product code) and first carriage return comes in to the program, the default button is activated, triggering a query of the database on the 1st value. If the a certain flag (prompt for qty) is set in the database for product record, then it pops up the 2nd window to prompt for the quantity, which is the 2nd value stored in the barcode. Some barcodes won't have the 2nd value. Since it all comes in as KB input, I wouldn't know whether or not to expect a 2nd value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85316/discussion-between-goobering-and-joemjr2).